# undefined is returned when pasring JSON with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a backend script produce a json response, that I'm trying to parse via jquery.

here is the reveals.

```
{"release": "Build version : 1.2.0.emt-4.1-1202", "timestamp": "52 Minutes"}
```

in the success portion of my ajax request, I'm trying to do the following.

```
success: function(result) {
 var json = JSON.parse(result);
     console.log(json); 
     console.log(json.timestamp); 
}
```

console.log response.

```
Object {"release": "Build version : 4.2.0.emt-4.2-10502", "timestamp": "52 Minutes"}
```

and alert response

```
check:205 undefined
```

I'm not sure why it keeps showing as undefined, how can I parse it correctly?

Comment: What does the rest of your `$.ajax` call look like? The body may already be json.

Comment: Your response should be in quote, checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response should be in quote like: `'{"release": "Build version : 1.2.0.emt-4.1-1202", "timestamp": "52 Minutes"}'`

**Check out demo**

```js
var json = JSON.parse('{"release": "Build version : 1.2.0.emt-4.1-1202", "timestamp": "52 Minutes"}');
     console.log(json); 
     console.log(json.timestamp); 
alert(json.timestamp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON` is probably already parsed.  Your success function should have the parsed `JSON` as a javascript object `result`.

Comment: If I use $.each without parsing result, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' ", it seems it only works with objects.

Comment: @Deano log `result` see if it is an object...`console.log(result);`. Post the result of logging `result`.

Answer (score 0):

You need not parse your result again as it is already in `JSON` format.

But one thing that you should have encountered is an error on this line `var json = JSON.parse(result);` which is when the result is already in this format.